# Making an image gallery in MS Word 2307

Tags: image, gallery, slideshow

I want to make a simple slideshow or other photo gallery (you know, several images stacked up in one place and switching beetwen them on click), but I think that with "standard" options it's impossible. I tried to link the image to "send to back" option but I didn't find such an option. A quick Google search also yielded no results. Is there any addon, macro or something else that would help me with my problem?